# AWS Step function - Field Parameters is not supported in Choice state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, devops, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to create an AWS Step function, but it is showing an error message as `Field Parameters is not supported` in the Choice state inside a Parallel branch. I used the following code:

```
{
"Comment": "A Parallel Step Function",
"StartAt": "ParentStep",
"States":
{
  "ParentStep":
  {
    "Comment": "Parallel test execution to check the Input Flow",
    "Type": "Parallel",
    "End": true,
    "Branches":
    [
        {
            "Comment": "Parallel Execution 1",
            "StartAt": "branch1",
            "States":
            {
                "branch1":
                {
                    "Comment": "branch1 started",
                    "Parameters":
                    {
                        "testvalue1.$": "$.value1"
                    },
                    "Type": "Choice",
                    "Choices":
                    [
                        {
                            "Variable": "$.testvalue1",
                            "NumericEquals": 1,
                            "Next": "subbranch1"
                        },
                        {
                            "Not":
                            {
                                "Variable": "$.testvalue1",
                                "NumericEquals": 1
                            },
                            "Next": "subbranch2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Default": "subbranch2"
                },
                "subbranch1":
                {
                    "Comment": "sub-branch 1",
                    "Type": "Pass",
                    "End": true
                },
                "subbranch2":
                {
                    "Comment": "Ending branch 1",
                    "Type": "Pass",
                    "End": true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Comment": "Parallel Execution 2",
            "StartAt": "branch2",
            "States":
            {
                "branch2":
                {
                    "Comment": "starting branch 2",
                    "Parameters":
                    {
                        "testvalue2.$": "$.value2"
                    },
                    "Type": "Choice",
                    "Choices":
                    [
                        {
                            "Variable": "$.testvalue2",
                            "NumericEquals": 2,
                            "Next": "subbranch3"
                        },
                        {
                            "Not":
                            {
                                "Variable": "$.testvalue2",
                                "NumericEquals": 2
                            },
                            "Next": "subbranch4"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Default": "subbranch4"
                },
                "subbranch3":
                {
                    "Comment": "sub-branch 3",
                    "Type": "Pass",
                    "End": true
                },
                "subbranch4":
                {
                    "Comment": "Ending Parallel Execution 2",
                    "Type": "Pass",
                    "End": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}}}
```

However, the same code works if I replace the `Choice` state with a `Task` state. Is the field `Parameters` is not supported in the `Choice` state? I went through the AWS Step function documentation and couldn't see any information about this. Can someone shed some light on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`Parameters` at `Choice` state is not supporeted. As per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html), you can only use `Choices` and `Default`. Also, you can check which fields are supported at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-states.html). By the way, you can achieve your task by the following solution.

```json
{
  "Comment": "A Parallel Step Function",
  "StartAt": "ParentStep",
  "States": {
    "ParentStep": {
      "Comment": "Parallel test execution to check the Input Flow",
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "End": true,
      "Branches": [
        {
          "Comment": "Parallel Execution 1",
          "StartAt": "branch1",
          "States": {
            "branch1": {
              "Comment": "branch1 started",
              "Type": "Choice",
              "Choices": [
                {
                  "Variable": "$.testvalue1",
                  "NumericEquals": 1,
                  "Next": "subbranch1"
                },
                {
                  "Not": {
                    "Variable": "$.testvalue1",
                    "NumericEquals": 1
                  },
                  "Next": "subbranch2"
                }
              ],
              "Default": "subbranch2"
            },
            "subbranch1": {
              "Comment": "sub-branch 1",
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Parameters": {
                "testvalue1.$": "$.value1"
              },
              "End": true
            },
            "subbranch2": {
              "Comment": "Ending branch 1",
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Parameters": {
                "testvalue1.$": "$.value1"
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "Comment": "Parallel Execution 2",
          "StartAt": "branch2",
          "States": {
            "branch2": {
              "Comment": "starting branch 2",
              "Type": "Choice",
              "Choices": [
                {
                  "Variable": "$.testvalue2",
                  "NumericEquals": 2,
                  "Next": "subbranch3"
                },
                {
                  "Not": {
                    "Variable": "$.testvalue2",
                    "NumericEquals": 2
                  },
                  "Next": "subbranch4"
                }
              ],
              "Default": "subbranch4"
            },
            "subbranch3": {
              "Comment": "sub-branch 3",
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Parameters": {
                "testvalue2.$": "$.value2"
              },
              "End": true
            },
            "subbranch4": {
              "Comment": "Ending Parallel Execution 2",
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Parameters": {
                "testvalue2.$": "$.value2"
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```